# How to check if DOM element and/or attribute is valid?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an array of elements:
`var elements = ['div', 'a', 'p', 'foo']`

I also have an array of attributes:
`var attributes = ['src', 'href', 'quux', 'id']`

*I want to understand how I can validate if the combinations of the above would make a valid DOM object.*
Or, in other words:
*How can I validate a DOM object against the DOM schema?**

For example (based on the above elements and attributes):

```
DOM_result = '<div src />';  // = false
DOM_result = '<div href />'; // = false
DOM_result = '<div quux />'; // = false
DOM_result = '<div id />';   // = true
DOM_result = '<a src />';    // = false
DOM_result = '<a href />';   // = true
DOM_result = '<a quux />';   // = false
DOM_result = '<a id />';     // = true
etc...
```

* = not sure if this is called *DOM schema*.

PS:
In my example I'm using JS, but please consider this question scripting language agnostic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most content attributes are [reflected](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflect) by an IDL attribute (a.k.a property) with the same name.

Those IDL attributes are implemented as accessor properties (i.e. getters and setters) in an interface from which the elements inherit from.

Therefore, you can create an element of the desired type and check if it has the desired property:

```
'src' in document.createElement('div'); // false
'src' in document.createElement('img'); // true
```

Note IDL attributes are case-sensitive, and some have different names than content attributes, e.g. you should check `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I need. Thanks also for the W3 link, very helpful!

Comment: one more question, do you know if it's possible to show the `document.createElement()` as an object? So that I can see all its content?

Comment: @bvl Do you mean you want to see all of its properties? You can use a `for...in` loop to iterate the enumerable ones (both own and inherited): `for(var prop in document.createElement('div')){ console.log(prop) }`

Comment: This works in, say, HTML, e.g. checking the attribute 'src' for the element 'img'. However, it does not seem to work in SVG, e.g. checking the attribute 'fill' for the element 'rect'. This is true whether using `createElement` or `createElementNS` (i.e. the name-spaced version). Looping through all the properties of the 'rect' element shows that `document.createElement(NS)` does return a list of attribute names, but only those like 'id', etc., not those specific to SVG, e.g. 'fill'. Anyone have any suggestions? I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46410518/5218951).