# How to filter object keys for all valid attributes of a specified HTML tag

Tags: javascript, typescript

Anybody knows a good way to filter out the valid keys/props from an object given a HTML tag?

```js
// imagine having some object with a random set of keys (some of which are valid HTML attribute keys)
const obj = { ... };

// I am looking for something like the following:
const validDivAttributesObj = filterValidHTMLAttributes(obj, "div")

// or even something like this
isValidHTMLAttribute("foo", "div") // false
isValidHTMLAttribute("href", "div") // false
isValidHTMLAttribute("class", "div") // true
isValidHTMLAttribute("href", "a") // true
```

That helper function can accept any valid HTML tag key as the second argument. Does anything like this exist in some kind of JS library?

Comment: So you want to check if (eg) `foo` is a valid attribute for `div` ?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585354/18057908) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the element with `document.createElement`, then check if the key exists using the `in` operator.

```js
const specialAttrs = {'class': 'className', 'for': 'htmlFor'}; 
// handle some special values that have different names in JavaScript

function isValidHTMLAttribute(attr, el) {
  return (specialAttrs[attr] ?? attr) in document.createElement(el);
}

console.log(isValidHTMLAttribute("foo", "div")) // false
console.log(isValidHTMLAttribute("href", "div")) // false
console.log(isValidHTMLAttribute("class", "div")) // true
console.log(isValidHTMLAttribute("href", "a")) // true
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you close this a an dupe?